# Python OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for datetime.timestamp()

Tags: python, timestamp

I got the issue in Python 3.9 under Windows, for datetime.timestamp():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\qgate-sln-mlrun\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-1a3ac1c0825d>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime(year=3021, month=11, day=13).timestamp()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

For this part of code:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=11, day=13).timestamp()
datetime.datetime(year=1021, month=11, day=13).timestamp()
datetime.datetime(year=3021, month=11, day=13).timestamp()
```

The strange is, it works correctly under Linux. Did you solve the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python 3.9 in Windows contains error. It is possible to solve the issue based on these options:

**1] Use timezone (it works in Python 3.9)**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=11, day=13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
1636761600.0
>>> datetime.datetime(year=1021, month=11, day=13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
-29920233600.0
>>> datetime.datetime(year=3021, month=11, day=13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
33193670400.0
```

**2] or use higher Python version e.g. 3.10**

BTW: I saw useful discussion about it here https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/94757